# Call scipy.stats probability distributions like normal python functions

Tags: python, function, statistics, scipy

```
from scipy.stats import uniform
```

How can I call `uniform.pdf` like a normal python function? I want to work with the probablility distribution functions like one can work with regular python functions in terms of integration and differentiation.

```
integrate.quad(uniform.pdf, xlimits['value'][0], xlimits['value'][1]))
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Unexpected output? Why do you think this doesn't work?

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake defining the function through `loc` and `scale`. It actually works.

Comment: Should I delete the question then?

Comment: You could edit it to clarify the actual problem, and [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution you have found, but as it stands I'd say it's not worth keeping around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.stats.uniform.pdf` is a Python function meaning that it is callable just like any other function.

```
from scipy.stats import uniform
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,10)

pdf = uniform.pdf(x) # Create a uniform pdf over the range [0,1].

print(pdf)
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

You can see the arguments that `uniform.pdf()` takes [at the bottom of this docs page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html#scipy.stats.uniform).